In SQL Server, can I get data from XML compressed in ZIP/RAR file saved as VARBINARY
I have a table column contains VARBINARY (data like 0x...) [Column name is LDATA]
I just want to be simple to be understood.
The software puts in LDATA column a ZIP/RAR contains one XML file.
To reach the XML file, i need to do those in order:

Convert varbinary to base64 in SQL Server
Use that base64 code to get the ZIP/RAR file (using online decoders)
Extract the XML out of ZIP/RAR (using WinRar)
Then read (Using Notepad++ etc)

I just want to read the XML file using only SQL Server (Using C# etc is NOT an option).
Is it possible?
Thanks in advance.

What about SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)?

Is Powershell an option? SQL Server doesn't have anything that can parse a ZIP or RAR, only a bare gzip or deflate blob. On a side note, a better option might have been to store it as xml data type and use XML Compression.

It is not an option too, unfortunately.

Why not? Every Windows machine comes with it. Or on Linux you can use gunzip or similar. Or rather: what actual software are you using to read the varbinary that means you can't use these options.

Indeed, i need that XML in a software that can handle SQL Server queries, so i cannot use SSIS, powershell or any other 3rd party programs.

Is an SQLCLR function an option? And what is the exact type of the file, is it ZIP, RAR, GZIP, something else?

It is a ZIP file. Yes, SQLCLR is an option, what can we do?

Your only option given you restrictions seems to be a SQLCLR scalar function.
// compile for .NET 4.8
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;  
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MySqlClr
{
    public class ZipHelpers
    {
        [SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true)]
        public static SqlBytes Unzip(byte[] zipped, string? entryName)
        {
            using (var archive = new ZipArchive(new MemoryStream(zipped), ZipArchiveMode.Read))
            {
                var entry = archive.Entries.FirstOrDefault(e => entryName == null || entryName == e.Name)
                    ?? throw new Exception("No entries in zip");
                using (var file = entry.Open())
                {
                    var ms = new MemoryStream();
                    file.CopyTo(ms);
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    return new SqlBytes(ms);
                }
        }
    }  
}  

You will need to add this as an UNSAFE assembly, which means you will need to sign it, create an Asymmetric Key or a Certificate from the signature, and then create a SQL Server Login (not User) from that key/cert, and give the login the UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission.
You also need to first do the same for the System.IO.Compression library, except that you can use the signature it already has.
Then you can create the function and use it
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Unzip(@zipped varbinary(max), @entryName nvarchar(256))
RETURNS varbinary(max)
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS EXTERNAL NAME [YourAssembly].[MySqlClr.ZipHelpers].[Unzip];


Then you can use this function to unzip the file, and just cast it to XML.
SELECT
  Id,
  COMVERT(xml, dbo.Unzip(YourBlob, NULL)) AS Unzipped
FROM YourTable;


Does this code handle convertion from base64 to ZIP?

No why would you need that? Your original data is not in base64, it's a varbinary byte string, and the output is the same. You only needed base64 because you were using an online converter.

Dear @Charlieface, I tried to do what u ve written. Created a new project in VSC 2022 (17.10.3) selecting "SQL Server Database Project", then added "New Item" selecting from "SQL CLR C#" the User Defined Function. But i couldnt add System.IO.Compression library from nuget, getting "Project 'Default' is not found." error. In PMC, i cannot select a default project although i ve just one. I need to use the library for ZipArchive. What am i missing?

You don't need a Nuget package for it, it's part of .NET Framework 4.8

https://imgur.com/a/faMaYxa

I was thinking that i dont need nuget, but if u examine previous pic, there is a problem...

Which framework version are you targetting?

https://ibb.co/DpmRjnR

Instead of clicking "Install package System.IO.Compression" click "using System.IO.Compression (from System.IO.Compression)" because in 4.8 it's part of the framework, you just need to add a library reference. You can also do this from the Solution Explorer, right click the project and Add Reference. In new style SDK project files you can add it in the XML as <Reference Include="System.IO.Compression" />

Using "References" worked, but i have a brand new problem: https://ibb.co/zby0f40

You're missing a using System.Linq; also why is ZipHelpers nested inside another class? Are you sure you are comfortable coding up C#, because these are basic issues.

Thanks for ur efforts but couldnt help. We possibly r not on the same page. I think u didnt use VSC as i use, mentioned above comment starting with "Dear @Charlieface". I cannot even Build the project cuz .NET 4.8 doesnt use C#8. System.Linq cannot be added to references and i ended up getting this error: "Error:  CS8370: Feature 'using declarations' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater."

OK these are all solvable problems, but they are not for this kind of discussion. I suggest you research them. C#8 certainly can be used with .NET Framework, even C#11 can, you just need to change LangVersion in your project file (and possibly add some polyfill libraries or classes for some new features). Just because the template uses an old version doesn't mean it can't be changed. In any event using declarations can be easily converted back to the old style using blocks with braces.
